# Latest update to 16.04 breaks wifi, sound

Tags: networking, sound, kernel, dell

With today's update to 4.4.0.43 kernel in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Dell XPS, both sound & wifi stopped working.  The computer does not believe it has either sound or wifi.  (This update was done via the normal, automated updater.)

I was able to boot back into the .42 kernel in grub, and that works as before,
uname -a included, FYI:

Linux ELIDED-xps 4.4.0-42-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 23:11:45 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

But the most recent update is basically nonfunctional without networking.

Is there a fix?  Do I need to be in the .43 kernel to apply it, etc.?

Please advise.

Comment: If the bug came out today I highly doubt a fix is available. But you can start googling the bug and it should start appearing on bug reports soon. Then get placed on the e-mailing list to monitor fixes.

Comment: I guess my main currrent concern is to be sure that the issue is properly reported. Should I be doing that differently?

Comment: this is definitely not the place to report bugs. Check out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Well,  this is presumably also not the place to ask for bug reporting help, but the problem with using the ubuntu-bug program is that if I'm in the .43 kernel, I have no internet. And if I have internet, I don't have the .43 'linux' to report the bug against.

Comment: Sounds like a catch 22... unless you have an ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

There arem many reports about the latest kernel not working for users.
the easiest solution for now would be to boot to a older kernel wich does not contain the bug or issues mentioned

See this article on how to boot older kernels trough grub

[How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Answer (score 0):

The same problem for me, 16.04 (4.4.0.43-generic) update. It broke my WiFi, the driver (ath9k) not available from the image package. I currently loaded the older version (4.4.0.42-generic), and it work well now. I think the problem is on uncompleted update package.

try run :

```
modprobe -r <module-name>
```

to unload related module to check whether the driver is loaded or not.

make sure if the module not available from the package, try load the module :

```
modprobe <module-name>
```

if "not found" error appear, for sure the driver not available from the package.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
With Kernel 4.4.0.43 I had problems like :
-no second monitor
-no internet (lan or wifi)
-no bluetooth
-no sd card reader
I solved restarting the machine selecting via Grub previous generic kernel 4.4.0.42 
and then removing the 43 kernel with Synaptic (option "mark for complete removal")

It now starts on its own without having to select the right kernel on Grub.

you can wait for kernel .44 right? I will.